# Extract some columns data from one table and insert into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.5, insert

I have a table with 16,000 records and need to get out some columns and then insert values in multiples tables. For example, suppose I have the following tables

- tbl_1: id, name, lastname
- tbl_2: id, name
- tbl_3: id, lastname

I need to get the values from tbl_1 and then insert in tbl_2 and tbl_3 meaning tbl1.name goes to tbl_2.name and tbl_1.lastname goes to tbl3.lastname. Is this possible using SQL queries?

I'm using MySQL latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are preserving the `id` assocaited with each name and lastname, run this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_2 (id,name) SELECT id,name FROM tbl_1;
INSERT INTO tbl_3 (id,lastname) SELECT id,lastname FROM tbl_1;
```

If tabless tbl_2 and tbl_3 already have data and you wish to overwrite it, run this:

```
REPLACE INTO tbl_2 (id,name) SELECT id,name FROM tbl_1;
REPLACE INTO tbl_3 (id,lastname) SELECT id,lastname FROM tbl_1;
```

If you are not preserving the ID, then run this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_2 (name) SELECT name FROM tbl_1;
INSERT INTO tbl_3 (lastname) SELECT lastname FROM tbl_1;
```

Comment: Hi @rolandomysqldba assuming the ID aren't preserved then I use the same sintax but removing the id field, I'm right?

Comment: Updating my answer...